# Django 404 pages not appearing?

Tags: django, google-chrome

I want to add a 404 page on my Django site.

I've created a template, `404.html`, and saved it in the root of my /templates directory. I've also made sure that the

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
```

line is included at the top of urls.py. I've set DEBUG to False. (I've been following [these instructions](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/#write-a-404-page-not-found-view).)

However, if I try to go to a page that I know doesn't exist - whether a made-up URL or a view specifically designed to do `get_object_or_404` - the 404 page doesn't appear: I just get Chrome's standard 'Oops! This link appears to be broken' page.

Oddly, I also have a 500.html template in the same place and that is appearing just fine if I generate a 500 error. What might the problem be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that's a problem with Chrome not serving error pages properly - try unticking the "Show suggestions for navigation errors" box in the "Under the Hood" section of Chrome's options.

Comment: That's exactly what it is, thanks. Should probably have tried that myself :)

Answer (score 3):

Start by checking this behavior in another browser. Chrome "hijacks" short 404 error pages and replaces them with it's own 'Oops! This link appears to be broken' page.