# Custom 404 django template

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to customize the 404 error pages in my application. After searching many possible solutions, I created an 404.html template, added a method which should handle HTTP Error 404 and edited my urls.py.

But I guess I'm doing something really wrong. My log presents an invalid syntax error and I cannot solve it.

My views.py:

```
# HTTP Error 400
def page_not_found(request):
    response = render_to_response('404.html',context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    response.status_code = 404

    return response
```

And the syntax error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/.../myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 393, in urlconf_module
return self._urlconf_module
AttributeError: 'RegexURLResolver' object has no attribute '_urlconf_module'
...
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/home/dcaled/work/portal-interface/portal/urls.py", line 12
handler404 = 'views.handler404'
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Does anyone have an idea of what's going on?
Thanks.

**UPDATE:** 
After @Alasdair suggestion, I made some changes and fixes. The error has stopped.

Now, my urls.py is like:

```
handler404 = 'views.page_not_found'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home),]
```

But I still don't get my custom 404.html when accessing a non existing page.
Instead, a default page is loaded, with this message:

"**Not Found**

The requested URL /url/404 not found on this server."

Also, my settings.py:

```
DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR , 'portal/templates'),)

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

My project tree:

```
├── fb_dev
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── manage.py
│
└── portal
    ├── admin.py
    ├── forms.py
    ├── json
    ├── migrations
    ├── models.py
    ├── static
    ├── templates
    │   ├── 404.html
    │   └── portal
    │       ├── base.html
    │       ├── home.html
    ├── templatetags
    ├── urls.py
    └── views.py
```

Comment: Which version of Django are you using? Where is your `404.html` template located?

Comment: My version is 1.8.5. And I updated the question with the template location.

Comment: Do you have a `TEMPLATES` setting? Do other parts of your code successfuly find templates in `portal/templates`? Could it be your [browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642340/django-404-page-not-showing-up) or your server (e.g. Apache) hijacking the 404 page.

Comment: @Alasdair, thanks for continuing helping me. Yes, I have a TEMPLATES setting. I edited my question with it. Yes, other parts of my code find templates there. I don't know if my browser is hijacking the 404 page. This error happens with Firefox. At Chrome, it loads a "Server Error (500)" page. And I'm locally running it. It's strange that when debugging, it seems to never enter my page_not_found method.

Comment: You should remove `TEMPLATE_DIRS` - it's obsolete and you already have the `TEMPLATES` setting. If `portal` is in your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting, then leaving `'DIRS': []` should be fine. As I said in your answer, I think you should remove your `handler404` line completely. Your view isn't doing anything special, so you let Django use the default one.

Comment: You should get the same response code in both browsers - getting a 500 in one and a 404 in another is strange. If you have a 500 server error, then you need to find the traceback, either from the logs, the email sent to the admin or the debug page if `DEBUG = True`. Apart from that, I can't spot any problems. Hope you figure out the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After some months, I revisited the problem and identified a solution. Here is the answer:

a) I removed `page_not_found` method from the **views.py**. There's no need to add it. Django automatically gets and renders the 404.html template.

b) Once again, there's no need to edit **urls.py**. So I removed this line:

```
handler404 = 'views.page_not_found'
```

c) Also, it is necessary to edit **settings.py**, setting `DEBUG` to `FALSE`.

```
DEBUG = False
```

And I removed the following line:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR , 'portal/templates'),)
```

d) Finally, I created a 404.html template in my `portal/templates` directory. It is worth noticing that the custom template was rendered only when placed inside this directory.

Answer (score 3):

After some troubles, the revy solution worked perfectly. So, just to clarify:

The Two things to do are:

- Add a `404.html` file in `your_app/template/404.html`
- Set your DEBUG value to False

After that, Django will render automatically your template.

Answer (score 2):

The `handler404` should be outside `urlpatterns`. If the view is called `page_not_found`, then it should refer to `page_not_found`, not `handler404`.

```
handler404 = 'views.page_not_found'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home),
]
```

However, in your case, you do not need a custom 404 handler at all. Remove the `handler404` line completely, and the default [`page_not_found`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/views/#django.views.defaults.page_not_found) view will render your `404.html` template.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I made these changes, but it still does not show a customized 404 page. It only shows "Not Found
The requested URL /url/404 not found on this server." Any other idea?

Comment: No. DEBUG is False, actually.